# Implementing Shor's algorithm on IBM Quantum Composer

Tags: ibm-q-experience, shors-algorithm

I'm trying to recreate [image]

from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00768) in the IBM Quantum Composer.  However, this circuit isn't enough understandable for me to do so.

I have tried to recreate the above circuit in the composer as follows

[image]

I've tried to recreate the following two gates for the MEF

[image]

as U(0,0,0,0) and nG2 where nG2 is

[image]

Obviously, I can be sure that my approach is wrong as I even don't know how to make one measurement affect the next one *(recreate the lines conecting measurements with $R_{\pi/2}$ and $R_{\pi/4}$)* and how to implement the MEF gates.

How should I recreate the given circuit in the IBM Quantum Composer to obtain the factors of $N=15$ ?